# Google Maps API with a Django Website

Tags: javascript, mysql, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a small website and am using the Django framework for my development. Parts of the site also includes using Google Maps APIs (V3), which includes using MySQL to add and save marker information as shown within the official Google documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

I have the basic maps working fine with being able to add a marker when it is clicked, but am having difficulties to get it to work since trying to implement the MySQL into it - the map does not load within the canvas on the page. I have copied the code exactly from the link above just to see if i could get it working basic but no joy.

Before I go posting up snippets of code here and there, I'm just wondering if maybe there might be a problem in the MySQL working within the Django development - I have a MySQL database synced with Django and have it running.

If there is any other way around getting markers and information to save to a map, like the example above, it would be great but I cant find anything anywhere.

I also looked at this guide but with similar results: 
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/10/google-map-v3-editing-saving-marker-in-database

Comment: How does MySQL have anything to do with the Javascript you use to display the maps?

Comment: MySQL has nothing to do with displaying the maps, but it used to save and load the markers and corresponding info to/from the mysql database. it's just since implementing this that the map wont display